# Trying to run few awk commands stored in file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with below commands

```
cat /some/dir/with/files/file1_name.tsv|awk -F "\\t" '{print $21$19$23$15}'
cat /some/dir/with/files/file2_name.tsv|awk -F "\\t" '{print $2$13$3$15}'
cat /some/dir/with/files/file3_name.tsv|awk -F "\\t" '{print $22$19$3$15}'
```

When i loop through the file to run the command, i get below error

```
cat file | while read line; do $line; done
cat: invalid option -- 'F'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Avoid useless `cat` and you can just run the file as `bash file` without any looping + reading line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the command properly as you intended it. Since you are reading line by line on the file (for unknown reason) you could call the interpreter directly as below

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ for running under 'bash' shell

while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf "%s" "$line" | bash
done <file
```

But this has an overhead of creating a forking a new process for each line of the file. If your commands present under `file` are *harmless* and is safe to be run in one shot, you can just as

```
bash file
```

and be done with it.

Also for using `awk`, just do as below for each of the lines to avoid useless `cat`

```
awk -F "\\t" '{print $21$19$23$15}' file1_name.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the pipe (`|`) symbol to act as you are accustomed to, but it doesn't.  To help you understand, try this :

```
A="ls / | grep e" # Loads a variable with a command with pipe
$A                # Does not work
eval "$A"         # Works
```

When expanding a variable without using `eval`, expansion and word splitting occurs after the shell interprets redirections and pipes, so your pipe symbol is seen just as a literal character.

Some options you have :

**A)** Avoid piping, by passing the file name as an argument

```
awk -F "\\t" '{print $21$19$23$15}' /some/dir/with/files/file1_name.tsv
```

**B)** Use `eval` as shown below, the potential security implications of which I would suggest you to research.

**C)** Put arguments in `file` and parse it, avoiding the use of `eval`, something like :

```
# Assumes arguments separated by spaces
IFS=" " read -r -a arguments;
awk "${arguments[@]-}"
```

**D)** Implement the parsing of your data files in Bash instead of `awk`, and use your configuration file to specify output without the need for expanding anything (e.g. by specifying fields to print separated by spaces).

The first three approaches involve some form of interpretation of outside data as code, and that comes with risks if the file used as input cannot be guaranteed safe.  Approach C might be considered a bit better in that regard, but since the command you are calling is `awk`, an actual program is passed to `awk`, so whatever `awk` can do, an attacker (or careless user) with write access to your file can cause your script to do anything `awk` can do.